# How to determine Debug mode on a Clustered Server in Visual Studio Code Editor

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

Usually on Visual Studio Professional we can do this in C#

```
#if DEBUG
 //doing something
#else
 //Release mode doing something
#endif
```

My NodeJS server environment is clustered so I need to check for debug mode to set some variables on.

Obviously I don't wanna put this '#' to certify about the debug mode, I'm just wondering if the Editor set some `process` variable to check for it.

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889470/how-to-programmatically-detect-debug-mode-in-nodejs

Comment: Nops, I'm using Visual Studio Code to debug, it raises my server up. But my env is clustered so it's not working properly with the native debug cause I need to set some variables only in debug mode.

Comment: Or this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376131/ifndef-in-javascript

Comment: This is only for Visual Studio Code Editor

Comment: DEBUG mode happens at compile time, not run-time, so it shouldn't make a difference how it's deployed (e.g. in a cluster). #if is called a Preprocessor Directive, which is a compiler instruction. #if DEBUG checks to see if the symbol DEBUG exists as a compile-time symbol. If it's not working, you need to modify how the assembly is being built before it's being deployed to make sure DEBUG is being passed as a symbol to the compiler.

Can you be more specific as to what's not working in the cluster?

Comment: My cluster is based on the Core Processor quantity, I'm looking for some flag that the Visual Studio Code raises when you play debuggging mode on it, got it?

Comment: When you start debugging from vs code it opens the process on the port 48448, when I run directly from my gulp task it opens on 5858. So I just made an IF to identify when the debug is running over VS Code or Gulp Task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice approach that I've found on this is to set an `ENV` variable on `launch.json` file as below:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/server.js",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development",

                // Here's my change
                "IS_DEBUG": true 
            },
            "externalConsole": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null
        }]
}
```

I've included a new property called `IS_DEBUG` and set it as `true` inside of `ENV`, so on my server file where I check on my `cluster` if the current `WORKER` is `MASTER` I've also included a check for this environment variable, eg:

```
if (!kernel.isMaster() && !process.env.IS_DEBUG) {
    // If this is true I fork the process in cluster
}
// Else I go forward initializing my database and so on 
else {
}
```