# Grunt-complexity on all the files in a directory

Tags: gruntjs, code-complexity

I'd like to run [Grunt-Complexity](https://github.com/vigetlabs/grunt-complexity) on all the files in a directory?
I'd like to get [this kind of output](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/f1db1459ea2144f96b10cc7c24608ed5bff9254d/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f76696765746c6162732f6772756e742d636f6d706c65786974792f6d61737465722f6578616d706c652e706e67).
Is there a way?
My js files are all under a subdirectory called "js".
Here's my gruntfile:

```
/*global module:false*/
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        // Task configuration.
        complexity: {
            generic: {
                src: ['grunt.js', 'js/*'],
                //exclude: ['doNotTest.js'],
                options: {
                    breakOnErrors: false,
                    jsLintXML: 'report.xml',         // create XML JSLint-like report 
                    checkstyleXML: 'checkstyle.xml', // create checkstyle report 
                    pmdXML: 'pmd.xml',               // create pmd report 
                    errorsOnly: false,               // show only maintainability errors 
                    cyclomatic: [3, 7, 12],          // or optionally a single value, like 3 
                    halstead: [8, 13, 20],           // or optionally a single value, like 8 
                    maintainability: 100,
                    hideComplexFunctions: false,     // only display maintainability 
                    broadcast: false                 // broadcast data over event-bus 
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // These plugins provide necessary tasks.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-complexity');

    // Default task.
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'complexity');
};
```

I'm simply calling this by typing

```
grunt
```

from the command line.
then if I type this

```
grunt complexity js/*
```

I get

```
Warning: Task "js/AgencyMediaController.js" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

And AgencyMediaController.js is the first file in my js directory. So it's having a look and listing the files, but then it crashes.

Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been quite a long while since I asked this question. I just ran into the same issue again and found the answer so here it is:

In the end it turned out to be that one of the files I was trying to analyse was causing the crash. This particular Javascript environment allows for [C-like preprocessor directives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13417842/4124574) and the Javascript file had something like this:

```
var mySettings = {
    //#ifdef FOO_CONSTANT
    setting : constants.FOO_SETTING
    //#endif
    //#ifdef BAR_CONSTANT
    setting : constants.BAR_SETTING
    //#endif
};
```

I guess the problem is that if this is read as strictly Javascript, the preprocessor directives are just plane comments, and there's a comma missing between the two properties, so Grunt complexity is unable to read this because of a syntax error. Using `--force` makes no difference BTW.

The annoying part is that this is all the error shows:

```
$ grunt --force
Running "complexity:generic" (complexity) task

Warning: undefined: Unexpected token, expected , (17570:1) Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.
```

So while it *does* say `expected , (175:1)` it *doesn't* say in *which* of the several Javascript files in this project the problem was found!

Just adding `exclude: ['path/to/MyFileWithPreprocessorDirectives.js']` to `Gruntfile.js` in order to exclude this file from the analysis gets me around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

example:
for all js file in JS folder:

```
src: ['js/**/*.js']
```

for ass .scss files in scss folder:

```
src: ['scss/**/*.scss']
```

I suggest for you create a config for your src folder can be easy in future folder changes in future projects:

sample:

```
            var src;
            config.src = src = {
                 sassMain        : 'scss/main.scss',
                 distFolder      : 'public/stylesheets/lovelycss.dist.css',
                 devFolder       : 'public/stylesheets/lovelycss.dev.css',
                 libFolder       : 'lib/**/*.js',
                 sassFolder      : 'scss/**/*.scss',
                 spriteCssFolder : 'scss/helpers/_sprite.scss',
                 spriteDestImg   : 'public/images/sprite/spritesheet.png',
                 spriteSrc       : 'public/images/min/*.{png,jpg,gif}',
                 imageminCwd     : 'public/images/',
                 imageminDest    : 'public/images/min'


            };


           //grunt Watch ===============================
            config.watch = {
                 scripts: {
                    files: ["<%= src.libFolder %>", "<%= src.sassFolder %>"]
                    ,tasks: ["dev", "sass:dist"]
                    //,tasks: ["dev",'sass:dist']
                 }
            }
```

I hope that helped you.

Comment: Hi Raduken, I tried this but all I get is this:
Running "complexity:generic" (complexity) task
Warning: Invalid source Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.

Comment: It's what I've posted above. That's all of it.